# Magento 2: Issue with salable quantity

Tags: magento2

I add new product and: qty=1 salableqty=1

Now I sold product and salableqty=0 but qty still = 1

Product still visible on frontend but impossible add to the basket.  Why system also not set for this product qty 0?

How to solve?https://prnt.sc/10iopbq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't manage the order processing inside Magento at all and still need to provide proper stock statuses on the shop pages, you can opt for the disabling of the Multiple stocks inventory functionalities, as the official documentation states:

> You may need to disable Inventory Management modules to:
> Use custom or third-party inventory and Order Management System (OMS) modules.

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/inventory-management/#disable-inventory-management

Now, if you check that article, you will see the full list of MSI modules that need disabling. This can be done with the `bin/magento module:disable` command and you need to specify the list of modules as argument.

I don't know which M2 version are you using, but I found that this article https://meetanshi.com/blog/disable-magento-msi/ provides the instructions for each M2 version.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

It is expected behavior, When a customer placed an order, the salable quantity is reduced and the quantity is not decreased. Qty will reduce when the admin creates the shipment for the order.

Please check the below screenshot about how salable qty works.
[image]

Please refer below links for more details.

https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations

Comment: Ok, but I use external sales management systems and I don't use the magento panel to create shipments at all. Is there any solution?

Comment: Check the configuration "Decrease Stock When Order is Placed"  https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/catalog/inventory.html or disable MSI if you didn't use it. Please be careful while disabling MSI extensions because it will clear the reservation table while disabling so we can't revert salable qty when enabling MSI again.